# Google Apps Script SES Initialization Intermittently Failing with Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-apps-script

We've been using Twitter Bootstrap within our Apps Script libraries for a good while now (circa 12 months) and it has been working perfectly. Of late however we've been faced with SES failures that result in our UI being completely inaccessible:

```
6 unexpected intrinsics
  ses.logger.console.undefined.log.forward
Max Severity: Not isolated(5) is not suitable for SES.
  ses.logger.console.undefined.log.forward
initSES failed.
  ses.logger.console.undefined.log.forward
Uncaught Error: SES not supported, aborting taming frame initialization.
```

We're including Bootstrap by the usual means ie

```
<style>
  Bootstrap source here (with a couple of changes)
</style>
```

One final point is that it seems to be account/device dependent because this occurs only for certain colleagues and not others. For instance I've had instances where a chromebook powerwash will resolve the issue and instances where it won't.

It's just plain odd. I would hate to have to refactor the code to remove Bootstrap, but has caja been updated? Would that cause an intermittent issue like this?

Answer (score 0):

I saw something similar to this when I upgraded to the beta channel of Chrome OS, v44, but it went away when I downgraded again to v43. It's similar to an issue that [popped up a few months back](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4303).

Comment: Yeah, I spotted that issue, but when a power wash didn't resolve it I wondered if there might be something afoot. There's something going awry, and I assumed it was something to do with bootstrap, but maybe not. Like you say I think I can correlate to a worsening with a recent beta release but can't be sure.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a result of a bug with Caja and will be fixed when an updated version is merged into Apps Script.

The ES6 Error object inheritance implementation in Chrome 44 (as Andrew Roberts found) is causing SES initialization to fail:

[Caja Issue 1966](https://github.com/google/caja/issues/1966)

This is being tracked as [Apps Script Issue 5084](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=5084) so if you're affected by this, please star the issue to let them know that it's affecting people.

In the meantime you need to be on Chrome 43, where we will be for now.